# Check filetypes before sending and do not proceed if not allowed?

Tags: php

How to add a check before sending the email whether the uploaded filetypes are allowed ?

I will upload files from different file-inputs (no multiple files in 1 input) and I want not to proceed when any of these files are not .jpg, .doc

How to do this?

```
if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'], 'base64',$_FILES['attachment']['type']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strstr()` to get the file format in temp like

```
if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {

      $check = strstr($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], "."); //get the file format
      if(($check == ".jpg") || ($check == ".doc")){
           //$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'], 'base64',$_FILES['attachment']['type']);
           print 'good';
      }else{
           echo $check." is not acceptable";
      }
}
```

Comment: Does this check all the uploaded files before printing the message? Because it is a must to check all the files and if at least 1 files is not allowed, to move to "error"

Comment: Yes it works for sure, Even if you upload a file without its extension it will print `" is not acceptable"`, Test all the possibilities before you deploy in live